# hide and show certaint row base on its id with jquery

Tags: jquery

I try to show and hide some row on click with jquery? So far, I try to get the id of a link that I click on then concatenate with some suffix then I try to toggle the row that has that id, so my html and query code something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>col_1</td>
        <td><a href="#" id="1" class="show_row">click me</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hide_row" id="1_preview">
        <td>Hiden contet</td>
        <td><a href="#" id="1" class="hide_row">done</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col_1</td>
        <td><a href="#" id="2" class="show_row">col_2</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hide_row" id="2_preview">
        <td>a</td>
        <td><a href="#" id="2" class="hide_row">done</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jquery:

```
$(".hide_row").hide();

$(".show_row").click(function() {
    var rowId = $(".show_row").attr('id');
    alert(rowId);
    $('#' + rowId + '_preview').show();
});
$(".hide_row").click(function() {
    var rowId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + rowId + '_preview').hide();
});
```

How can edit my jquery to work as I describe?

Comment: I will suggest please dont use id="1" , more than once. If you can use it as a class="1", will be better. Also please use a valid identifier name.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/47j47Lud/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
var rowId = $(".show_row").attr('id');
```

Use

```
var rowId = $(this).attr('id');
```

Because there are another elements inside DOM with class `show_row`
and rest of the small changes are inside fiddle see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/47j47Lud/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Your `<tr>` and `<a>` with the same class (`hide_row`) becomes hidden on load. Your `a.hide_row` is not displayed if `a.show_row` is clicked because it does not have the same ID that your `tr.hide_row` has. To solve your problem:

```
$("tr.hide_row").hide();

$(".show_row").click(function() {
    var rowId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(rowId);
    $('#' + rowId + '_preview').show();
});
$("a.hide_row").click(function() {
    var rowId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + rowId + '_preview').hide();
});
```